# Python, ldap3 e Apache Directory Studio

Tags: python, openldap

Tenho um servidor LDAP local criado no Apache Directory Studio, rodando na porta 10389.

Quando conecto utilizando php, consigo fazer pesquisas normalmente, mas quando tento conectar utilizando o módulo ldap3 do Python, não consigo fazer o Bind no servidor. A resposta sempre é um erro.

Utilizo as mesmas credenciais, tanto no PHP quanto no Python. A única configuração que eu não consegui fazer em Python e que utilizo no PHP é:

```
ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```

Alguém teria alguma luz?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando a biblioteca https://github.com/pyldap/pyldap é bem simples.

Segue um exemplo básico de uso:

```
>>> import ldap
>>> con = ldap.initialize('ldap://localhost:389', bytes_mode=False)
>>> con.simple_bind_s('login', 'secret_password')
>>> results = con.search_s('ou=people,dc=example,dc=org', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(cn=Raphaël)")
>>> results
[
    ("cn=Raphaël,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org", {
        'cn': [b'Rapha\xc3\xabl'],
        'sn': [b'Barrois'],
    }),
]
```

Creio que com isto você pode adaptar as suas necessidades.